# NamedPipeClientStream.Connect() throws System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find the specified file

Tags: c#

Can anyone please tell me why NamedPipeClientStream.Connect() would throw a System.IO.FileNotFoundException exception (Unable to find the specified file)? 
I thought the Connect() method will just block forever rather than throwing an exception.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

`NamedPipeClientStream.Connect()` is just managed wrapper over `WaitNamedPipe` and `CreateFile` kernel method.

More here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365800(v=vs.85).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx

The managed part looks like (simplified):

```
public void Connect(int timeout = -1) {
  int tickCount = Environment.TickCount;
  int elapsed = 0;
  SafePipeHandle safePipeHandle;
  while (true) {
    if (!WaitNamedPipe(normalizedPipePath, timeout - elapsed)) {
      int lastWin32Error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
      if (lastWin32Error != FILE_NOT_FOUND && lastWin32Error != SUCCESS) {
        ThrowWinIOError(lastWin32Error, string.Empty);
      }
    }
    if (timeout != -1 && (elapsed = Environment.TickCount - tickCount) >= timeout) {
      throw new TimeoutException();
    }

    safePipeHandle = CreateFile(normalizedPipePath, m_access, FileShare.None, null, FileMode.Open, num, null);
    if (!safePipeHandle.IsInvalid) {
      // success
      return;
    }
    int lastWin32Error2 = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    if (lastWin32Error2 == PIPE_BUSY) {
      continue;
    }
    ThrowWinIOError(lastWin32Error2, string.Empty);
  }
}
```

So it invokes `WaitNamedPipe` which returns immediatelly if pipe doesn't exist and managed code does the retry (it retries indefinetly if no timeout is specified). Tricky part is that `CreateFile` does no handling of FILE_NOT_FOUND error (it handles just PIPE_BUSY error) - I suspect this is where you can run into racial condition.

I.E.: `WaitNamedPipe` returns ok, but before `CreateFile` is hit the pipe  changed (went back to void after hibernation ?) and `CreateFile` throws exception you're seeing.

Workaround should be relatively simple - wrap `Connect` method to retry on FILE_NOT_FOUND `IOException`.